# Javascript does not open popup window with table and form in it

Tags: javascript, html

A long as the form contains any element the window won't open.
However if the form is empty (if you remove ) from the code, the popup works fine.

Javascript:

```
function openScheduleWindow() {
    var scheduleWindow = window.open("", "Schedule Window", "width=700, height=200");
    scheduleWindow.document.write("<html><body><table border=1> \
        <tr><th>C1</th><th>C2</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>A</td></tr> \
        <tr><td>2</td><td>B</td></tr> \
        </table><form><input type="text" name="firstname"></form>");
}
```

Comment: The `language` attribute has been deprecated for a long time. More common is to use `<script type="text/javascript">` if you want to be precise about the language.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to escape the `"`'s in the HTML string.

```
 scheduleWindow.document.write("<html><body><table border=1> \
        <tr><th>C1</th><th>C2</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>A</td></tr> \
        <tr><td>2</td><td>B</td></tr> \
        </table><form><input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\"></form>");
```

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes on the line `<input type="text" name="firstname">` is causing the problem try replacing them with single quotes, should work fine

```
function openScheduleWindow() {
  var scheduleWindow = window.open("", "Schedule Window", "width=700, height=200");
  scheduleWindow.document.write("<html><body><table border=1> <tr><th>C1</th><th>C2</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>A</td></tr> <tr><td>2</td><td>B</td></tr> </table><form><input type='text' name='firstname'></form>");
}
```